# Populate the solution of TimeFold.ai foodpackaging from DemoDataGenerator to an external JSON

Tags: java, json, maven, timefold

Goodmorning, today im trying to change the population of the solution of FoodPackaging in timefold.ai from the random data, generated from the class DemodataGenerator, to a JSON and trying to solve it with the data in this JSON, how could i do it?

Excpecting to change the data source from the class DemoDataGenerator to a JSON data reading

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at how the quarkus school timetabling quickstart architecture works. That way is much easier to replace the json file.

[image]

We intend to refactor the Food Packaging quickstart to this architecture too in the next few months. If you can't wait for that: it's not too difficult, give it a try.